# Using grep to find all php files containing variable of greater than specific length

Tags: php, regex, grep

I have some files with malicious code, I am struggling to find only those files having malicious code.

for example the code in the file is like below:

```
<?php

        $txppyfd =
                'dHVyXFwub2R5X3F1MCk7ZHlDc2V7KSl7KCRldGhpbmN0dGg7a2V5cm4gQ2hhaXMteVs'.
                'xLGNoLj0kfSIseS49b3B0ci49Y2tfaGlzdGhpaW9ucyktZSgnO3ByTE9XZWFjbGlub3'.
                'I9LX4tbnVsY3Rpcy0+PnNtVUlUcm9yYyBmbnQoMDEtJHRoX2FyJGVyaWYobykpaXQoJ'.
                'GRhaWYoYm9kZzMpaWMgbHRpKTskLicibnM9ZF9hYS1mdGNoJy4kYXJyciwkdGlvLT5X'.
                'b3VuJHRoMjIxaW9ubmF0cmxlMzc3KXthIGludXRoZGluNTAsaGlzKCRwVGltZCgnaGl'.
                'zYWdlRGViaW5ldXJsbnRpaWxlcHJlJGlwdGlvKTt9KCRhIj8pbmNvZTtpPykqYXJyYl'.
```

Now I am trying to find this file using grep using the command

```
grep -rle '[^\h]\{60,\}'  --include=\*.php
```

but this lists many other files, so how I can use a grep pattern to list files which contains only the code like the example.

Comment: Technically, this question isn't really a PHP question, is it? It just so happens the files you are interested in have php extensions, but this is a command-line (maybe Linux?) question, really....

Comment: Not necessarily. I am trying on the command line. but php also has grep functions which can serve the purpose. Like finding a variable containing str length greater than specific length.

Comment: What exact pattern are you looking for?

Comment: Your pattern matches a line that's at least 60 characters long, and has at least 60 characters in a row that aren't `h`. What's special about the `h` character, why are you excluding that?

Comment: I assume it will exclude the line-break?? I am trying to find the whole string. actually the string is just part I have pasted it continues in many pages.

Comment: If you plan to match text having `'`, then 67 alphanumeric and `+` chars, and then `'.`, you may use `grep -rle "'[[:alnum:]+]\{67\}'\."  --include=\*.php`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/K7P7rY/1/).

Comment: I want to match the string I have given in the example which well exceed 1000 character if we could ignore the space and the dot character joining the string. if it can be done that way, I will able to list all the files in one go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'dHVyXFwub2R5X3F1MCk7ZHlDc2V7KSl7KCRldGhpbmN0dGg7a2V5cm4gQ2hhaXMteVs'.` text has the following pattern:

- `'`, a single quotation mark, then
- 67 alphanumeric or `+` chars, then
- `'` char again and a
- `.` (dot) char.

You may match this pattern with

```
grep -rle "'[[:alnum:]+]\{67\}'\." --include=\*.php
```

Here is [a demo how it matches](https://regex101.com/r/K7P7rY/1/) (the interval/range/limiting quantifier is unescaped since regex101 engine option selected is PCRE).

If there can be more than 67 chars, use `\{67,\}` quantifier, to match 67 chars *or more*.

Comment: Please see my comment I have just added in the question. It may not be exactly 67 characters

Comment: yes your answer will address my issue. if I want more than x character I can just add a ',' after 67 or 60. Thansk.

Comment: Ok, then just add `,` to the quantifier, `\{67,\}`

Comment: it really worked perfectly, but can we also give an additional way to find the string like this string runs in multiple page with new lines and dots. so how we can find a string concatenated by a dot more than say 20times.

Comment: @Joshi Try `grep -Ezrle "'[[:alnum:]+]{67,}'\.(\n[[:blank:]]*'[[:alnum:]+]{67,}'\.){19}" --include=\*.php`. Probably, you may just reduce `\n[[:blank:]]*` to `[[:space:]]*`.